# Blog landing page amp is not shown in search console

Tags: amp-html

My amp blog (*xyz*) is not shown up in Google Search Console when searched using keywors *'xyz blog'*. The search results show only non amp version. But amp pages are shown when searched by any blog post title or using keyword amp along with search (*xyz blog amp*). Please help me in finding a solution for this?

Comment: Hey @priyaqb, please give a link to your blog to view. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Make sure your AMP landing has no error by adding `#development=1` or using Google validation tools. 2) Make sure that non-AMP page has `<link rel="amphtml" href="amp/url" />` tag.